# selendroid server error: Command aapt not found

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, aapt

Currently i am working on selenium web driver for automation testing.As i was interested in mobile app testing as well i have came across this selendroid.So working on how to do automation testing with selendroid.I have installed Eclipse ADT created a virtual device and installed selendroid-test-app in that.

I was trying to launch selendroid server but getting error as Command aapt not found.
Gone through many workarounds but none of them worked.The procedure i have followed is:

1) Launched android virtual device(selendroid-test app already installed in it)
2) i have set java path to jdk1.6 and android home path as D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk
3)from command prompt trying to launch selendroid server with the command :
java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar -aut selendroid-test-app-0.5.1.apk
4)at sdk\tools folder i have aapt.exe file and i copied the same to platform-tools folder as well.

This is the error i am getting

D:\selendroid>java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar -aut s
elendroid-test-app-0.5.1.apk

```
Nov 6, 2013 12:25:08 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher main
INFO: ################# Selendroid #################
Nov 6, 2013 12:25:08 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher lauchServer
INFO: Starting selendroid-server port 5555
Nov 6, 2013 12:25:08 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher lauchServer
SEVERE: Selendroid was not able to interact with the Android SDK: Command 'aapt'
was not found inside the Android SDK. Please update to the latest development t
ools and try again.
Nov 6, 2013 12:25:08 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher lauchServer
SEVERE: Please make sure you have the lastest version with the latest updates in
stalled:
Nov 6, 2013 12:25:08 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher lauchServer
SEVERE: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
Nov 6, 2013 12:25:08 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher$1 run
INFO: Shutting down Selendroid standalone
```

Also adding some part of verbose log for reference

```
rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Class$MethodArray from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.misc.ProxyGenerator$MethodInfo from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\r
t.jar]
[Loaded sun.misc.ProxyGenerator$ConstantPool$Entry from C:\Program Files\Java\jr
e6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.misc.ProxyGenerator$ConstantPool$ValueEntry from C:\Program Files\Ja
va\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.DataOutput from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.io.DataOutputStream from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.misc.ProxyGenerator$ConstantPool$IndirectEntry from C:\Program Files
\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.misc.ProxyGenerator$FieldInfo from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt
.jar]
[Loaded sun.misc.ProxyGenerator$PrimitiveTypeInfo from C:\Program Files\Java\jre
6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.misc.ProxyGenerator$ExceptionTableEntry from C:\Program Files\Java\j
re6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded $Proxy0 by instance of java.lang.reflect.Proxy]
[Loaded java.lang.annotation.Target from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.annotation.ElementType from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.
jar]
[Loaded java.lang.annotation.Documented from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded $Proxy1 by instance of java.lang.reflect.Proxy]
[Loaded java.util.ListIterator from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.AbstractList$ListItr from shared objects file]
[Loaded $Proxy2 by instance of java.lang.reflect.Proxy]
[Loaded $Proxy3 from sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException from C:\Program Files\Jav
a\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded com.beust.jcommander.ParametersDelegate from file:/D:/selendroid/selendr
oid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded com.beust.jcommander.DynamicParameter from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroi
d-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded com.beust.jcommander.WrappedParameter from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroi
d-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded com.beust.jcommander.StringKey from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-stand
alone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded com.beust.jcommander.ParameterDescription from file:/D:/selendroid/selen
droid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.AssertionError from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded com.beust.jcommander.Parameters from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-stan
dalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded java.util.Collections$EmptySet$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.
jar]
[Loaded com.beust.jcommander.ResourceBundle from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-
standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl from C:\Program Files\Java\jr
e6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\
lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.UnsafeBooleanFieldAccessorImpl from C:\Program Files\Java\jr
e6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl from shared objects file]
[Loaded com.beust.jcommander.Strings from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-standal
one-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded com.beust.jcommander.FuzzyMap from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-standa
lone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded com.beust.jcommander.IParameterValidator2 from file:/D:/selendroid/selen
droid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded java.util.LinkedList$ListItr from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.reflect.generics.repository.AbstractRepository from C:\Program Files
\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.generics.repository.FieldRepository from C:\Program Files\Ja
va\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\
rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl from C:\Pro
gram Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.generics.repository.GenericDeclRepository from C:\Program Fi
les\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository from C:\Program Files\Ja
va\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.generics.tree.FormalTypeParameter from C:\Program Files\Java
\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.generics.tree.TypeVariableSignature from C:\Program Files\Ja
va\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.reflect.generics.tree.Signature from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\
rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassSignature from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.LazyReflectiveObjectGenerator fro
m C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl from C:\Program
Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$Node from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$5 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$LastNode from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$Single from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$SliceNode from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$Slice from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$Begin from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$First from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$Start from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Pattern$TreeInfo from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.MatchResult from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.regex.Matcher from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.SortedSet from shared objects file]
Nov 6, 2013 12:49:09 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher lauchServer
INFO: Starting selendroid-server port 5555
[Loaded io.selendroid.server.SelendroidStandaloneServer from file:/D:/selendroid
/selendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded java.net.SocketAddress from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.net.InetSocketAddress from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.Executor from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded io.selendroid.server.ServerDetails from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-s
tandalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded org.webbitserver.HttpHandler from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-standal
one-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.Executors from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.ja
r]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib
\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService from C:\Program Files\Java\
jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\
lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler from C:\Program Files\Java
\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy from C:\Program File
s\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit$1 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit$2 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit$3 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit$4 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit$5 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit$6 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit$7 from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.j
ar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\r
t.jar]
[Loaded java.util.AbstractQueue from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\li
b\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$Transferer from C:\Program Files\J
ava\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack from C:\Program File
s\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack$SNode from C:\Progra
m Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\r
t.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.Executors$DefaultThreadFactory from C:\Program File
s\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject fr
om shared objects file]
[Loaded java.net.InetAddress from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.net.InetAddress$Cache from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.net.InetAddress$Cache$Type from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.net.InetAddressImplFactory from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.net.InetAddressImpl from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.net.Inet6AddressImpl from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameService from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.net.InetAddress$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.net.Inet4AddressImpl from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.net.Inet4Address from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.SubList from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.RandomAccessSubList from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.SubList$1 from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.net.URI from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.net.URI$Parser from shared objects file]
[Loaded org.webbitserver.WebServers from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-standalo
ne-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded org.webbitserver.Endpoint from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-standalone
-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded org.webbitserver.WebServer from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-standalon
e-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded org.webbitserver.netty.NettyWebServer from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroi
d-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded java.net.UnknownHostException from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.Callable from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar
]
[Loaded java.util.concurrent.Future from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded org.webbitserver.handler.exceptions.PrintStackTraceExceptionHandler from
file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded org.webbitserver.handler.exceptions.SilentExceptionHandler from file:/D:
/selendroid/selendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded org.webbitserver.handler.ServerHeaderHandler from file:/D:/selendroid/se
lendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded org.webbitserver.handler.DateHeaderHandler from file:/D:/selendroid/sele
ndroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded io.selendroid.server.model.SelendroidStandaloneDriver from file:/D:/sele
ndroid/selendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded io.selendroid.exceptions.AndroidDeviceException from file:/D:/selendroid
/selendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded io.selendroid.exceptions.ShellCommandException from file:/D:/selendroid/
selendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded io.selendroid.exceptions.SelendroidException from file:/D:/selendroid/se
lendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded io.selendroid.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException from file:/D:/selend
roid/selendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded io.selendroid.android.AndroidApp from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-sta
ndalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded io.selendroid.android.HardwareDeviceListener from file:/D:/selendroid/se
lendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded io.selendroid.android.DeviceManager from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-
standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded org.json.JSONException from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-standalone-0.
5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded io.selendroid.exceptions.DeviceStoreException from file:/D:/selendroid/s
elendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded io.selendroid.builder.SelendroidServerBuilder from file:/D:/selendroid/s
elendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveEntry from file:/D:/selendr
oid/selendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.ArchiveOutputStream from file:/D:/
selendroid/selendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream from fi
le:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded java.net.JarURLConnection from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$URLJarFileCloseController from share
d objects file]
[Loaded sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile from shared objects file]
[Loaded sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$URLJarFileEntry from shared objects
file]
[Loaded sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream from shared
objects file]
[Loaded io.selendroid.android.impl.DefaultAndroidApp from file:/D:/selendroid/se
lendroid-standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-
standalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded io.selendroid.android.AndroidSdk from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-sta
ndalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
[Loaded java.io.FileFilter from C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.ProcessEnvironment from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$NameComparator from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$EntryComparator from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.SortedMap from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.NavigableMap from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.TreeMap from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$CheckedEntrySet from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$CheckedEntrySet$1 from shared objects file]

[Loaded java.lang.ProcessEnvironment$CheckedEntry from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.TreeMap$Entry from shared objects file]
[Loaded io.selendroid.android.AndroidSdk$1 from file:/D:/selendroid/selendroid-s
tandalone-0.5.1-with-dependencies.jar]
Nov 6, 2013 12:49:09 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher lauchServer
SEVERE: Selendroid was not able to interact with the Android SDK: Command 'aapt'
was not found inside the Android SDK. Please update to the latest development t
ools and try again.
Nov 6, 2013 12:49:09 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher lauchServer
SEVERE: Please make sure you have the lastest version with the latest updates in
stalled:
Nov 6, 2013 12:49:09 PM io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher lauchServer
SEVERE: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeySet from shared objects file]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$IdentityHashMapIterator from shared objects fi
le]
[Loaded java.util.IdentityHashMap$KeyIterator from shared objects file]
Nov 6, 2013 12:49:09 PM `enter code here`io.selendroid.SelendroidLauncher$1 run
INFO: Shutting down Selendroid standalone
[Loaded sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$FileLockTable$Releaser from shared objects fi
le]
[Loaded sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$1 from shared objects file]
```

OS : windows 7 32 bit
In SDK Manager i dont find any updates available

Pls help.Struggling from many days..

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your JAVA_HOME points to a JDK: http://selendroid.io/setup.html

I recommend to use latest snapshot version (0.6.0-SNAPSHOT), because lately improvements especially for Windows has been added. You find the version here: 
http://ci.selendroid.io/job/selendroid/io.selendroid$selendroid-standalone/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the system is looking for the 'aapt' inside the 'build-tools' folder. Try installing latest version of 'Andriod SDK Build-tools' from the SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

Look at **ANDROID_HOME** variable, example:

> ANDROID_HOME=/home/joel/dev/android/android-sdk-linux

this must be exist.

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy the aapt.exe file from the Android\sdk\build-tools\nn.n.n\ directory (use the latest) to the Android\sdk\platform-tools directory...